# In Ant- Match Task, match to a set of String values

Tags: ant

In my filepath I want to check for specific directory names. If found, then only process.

My filepath values are like

1. force-app\main\default**aura**\TestCompDeploy\TestCompDeployHelper.js
2. force-app\main\default**lwc**\testLWCDeployComp\testLWCDeployComp.js
3. force-app\main\default**staticresources**\logo.jpeg

Below MATCH expression with a single string pattern works.

```
<matches string="${SamplePathTrial}" pattern="/aura/"/>
```

But a multi search pattern fails. How to do something like below?

```
<matches string="${SamplePathTrial}" pattern="['/aura/', '/lwc/', '/staticresources/']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The matches [`<condition>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) pattern is a regular expression, hence you'd likely need something like:

```
<matches string="${SamplePathTrial}" pattern="/aura/|/lwc/|/staticresources/" />
```

Pipe characters separate the alternate patterns, effectively saying "match /aura/ OR /lwc/ OR /staticresources/".

Comment: Thanks Martin. That worked like a charm. 

Also, any links/resources that guide on "generating" Regular expression patterns in Ant? I am aware of PropertyRegex and other similar tasks in Ant. Challenge is building a Regex pattern to specify to such RegEx tasks. Any tool to help generate and test the pattern? 

Right now I do a hit and trial of Regex patterns in Ant, that is too error prone and laborious. Thanks once again.